# How to model a Coral or Sponge Structure?

Tags: texturing, uv, vector-mapping, bump

Can you please give me advise how to make this model?
1) My target goal image is this (perfect copy of the real object)

[image]

2) Now I have a model of a knife, but I don't know how to apply a bump mapping to the handle so it looks similar to the target image. You can see that it has a deep relief structure and also a rough surface.

[image]

3) I tried use this cloth bump texture, without success. It should be more organic.

[image]

Comment: have a look at the Tissue add-on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67150/how-was-that-render-created-with-tissue-add-on

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you can get anything good with a bump map or procedurally, especially if you're supposed to make a "perfect copy", so I guess you'll have to make the mesh manually: create a cylinder, mirror it, use your picture as background to follow the shape, cut the holes profiles with the knife, extrude, add some edges with the knife to make a nice topology with quads, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the skin modifier tutorials in youtube. If you add a displacement modifier on top of it I'd imagine you could create something similar. The skin modifier creates the shape and the displacement could add more distortion and stretching to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).