# Modelling pollen 3d mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, wireframe

I am kind of a noob in blender, who's trying to model a grain of pollen for an ai experiment. The pollen grain is this one:
[image: Pollen microscope image]

And I don't know how to model that random wireframe that overlaps itself in blender, 'cause the blender wireframe modifier only lets me build a perfect wireframe with no overlapping.

I'm not native speaker so maybe some words are incorrect. Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: Try to find some noise images that are similar to it, and use this noise image as a displacement map.

Comment: You could use the [Tissue Add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67150/how-was-that-render-created-with-tissue-add-on) that comes bundled with Blender 2.8x. You have to activate it in "Menu - Edit- Preferences - Add-Ons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean with the random wireframe overlapping. To make this object I think you should fake the texture rather than model it, I see at least 2 ways:

- With a *Noise* node > *Height* of a *Bump* node > *Normal* of a *Diffuse*. Here I've even mixed 2 noises in a *MixRGB* to give a bit more complexity. I also added a *Layer Weight* at the end, if necessary.

[image]
[image]

- You could also create a repeatable texture from your original image. Unwrap your object, in the 3D view / *Texture Paint* mode, use the *Stencil* brush to paint on your object with your texture, and again use this with a *Bump* node.

[image]
[image]
[image]